# Why does this awk command not play as well with find as sed does?

Tags: find, sed, awk

I'm creating a **Bash shell script** to do some file manipulation on some HTML files.

Among the many actions I do, I have this `sed` command which works great:

```
find $DIR -type f -name '*.html' -exec sed -i 's/.*<script type="text\/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="file.js"><\/script>.*/<script type="text\/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="file2.js"><\/script>/g' {} \;
```

It looks through every HTML file in the directory in question, and replaces one line of text.

I wanted to do something similar where I replace multiple lines between two HTML coments.

So I want to take this:

```
<!-- STARTREPLACE1 -->
Blah
Blah
Blah
<!-- ENDREPLACE1 -->
```

And change it to:

```
<!-- STARTREPLACE1 -->
A whole new world!
<!-- ENDREPLACE1 -->
```

I found this `awk` command which seems to work when I run it on one file:

```
awk '/<!-- STARTREPLACE1 -->/{p=1;print;print "A whole new world!"}/<!-- ENDREPLACE1 -->/{p=0}!p' justonefile.html
```

So I thought I could do the same `find` function I use with `sed` and apply that method here in order to run this `awk` command on every HTML file in the directory:

```
find $DIR -type f -name '*.html' -exec awk '/<!-- STARTREPLACE1 -->/{p=1;print;print "A whole new world!"}/<!-- ENDREPLACE1 -->/{p=0}!p'
```

But when I run it, it says:

```
find: `-exec' no such parameter
```

Is there a way I can get my awk command to run on all the HTML files?

***Bonus question:*** Can I also remove the two tags around the text I want to replace? So `<!-- STARTREPLACE1 -->` and `<!-- ENDREPLACE1 -->` are removed and I only end up with:

```
A whole new world!
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you need to end the `-exec` action with `{} \;`.

Second, `awk` do not modify the file in place as `sed` do (with the `-i` option), so you should send the output to a temporary file, then move this to the original file.

Create a script (say we call it `replace`) with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
tfile=$(mktemp)
awk '/<!-- STARTREPLACE1 -->/{p=1;print;print "A whole new world!"} 
     /<!-- ENDREPLACE1 -->/  {p=0}' "$1" >"$tfile" && \
  mv "$tfile" "$1"
```

give it executable permissions

```
chmod +x ./replace
```

then run

```
find "$DIR" -type f -iname '*.html' -exec ./replace {} \;
```

Comment: Sounds like using a temporary file is a good idea. Any chance you could explain how I do that? Or can I change awk for sed and get the same result?

Comment: @DaveMG: I added something to my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for providing a method for acting on all the files. The only thing is there seems to be a bug in the code somewhere, because after running the ./replace script, all the HTML files are completely empty. Hmmm..

Comment: @DaveMG: yes, there was, I corrected it now. I hope you have tested it on a copy of the files.

Comment: It works now, but only if where you have `/  {p=0}'` is replaced by `/{p=0}!p'`. Thanks again so much for the code!

Answer (score 2):

And for the bonus:

```
gawk '{!p} /<!-- STARTREPLACE1 -->/{print "A whole new world!";p=1}/<!-- ENDREPLACE1 -->/{p=0}'
```

Comment: what is this supposed to do: `{!p}` ?

Comment: I tested this, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: errata - should be gawk '!p{} /<!-- STARTREPLACE1 -->/{print "A whole new world!";p=1}/<!-- ENDREPLACE1 -->/{p=0}' but it works for me with both syntax. Dave what do you mean Is doesn't do anything? Which awk version are you using?